# QGIS and Python 2.7 - cannot find qgis installation at /usr despite qgis being installed

Tags: qgis, python-2.7

I am trying to install python library qmesh but it seems to have issues with python3 so I am attempting with python2.7. I've got qgis 3.2.2 installed but I am getting an error saying 'Could not find a qgis installation at /usr'.

Comment: QGIS 3+ only supports Python3

Comment: How can I install an older version of qgis? It keeps installing qgis3.2.2 each time I install and try

Comment: Depends on the Linux distribution on how to install qgis-2.x and 3.x has been out for a while, so I would be surprised if many distros still packages qgis-2.x. You might have to use an older distro version get a stable version of qgis-2.x and THEN you might need to find a distro that provides the entire package repos as they may not still provide mirrors. Currently, Debian 'oldstable/Buster' still have 2.18 in their repos.